# Android Studio Errorr

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I try to run flutter code on the android emulator but what I get is an error as below.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not write cache value to 'C:\Users\jaga\.gradle\daemon\5.6.2\registry.bin'.

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code -1
```

Comment: Please follow the advice in the second bullet point and attach the resulting logs to your question. As it stands currently your post is too vague.

Answer (score 0):

```
Start

Type "cmd" + enter

cd to C:\Users\jaga.gradle\daemon\

Ctrl + A

Delete All

Restart Android Studio
```

Go To User -> Select user -> Gradle -> Daemon -> select version then select all and delete all

Then restart android studio.